# Start&End Date filters and Searchbox Filter Logic Tsql

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, parameters, where-clause

I am working on a ssrs report and the requirement for the report is ; Start & End date filters and Order number filter which will be searchbox. The report will show today's data but if they want to see previous days I have to have these 3 filters on my report.

My challenge is how to add the logic in where clause.
I tried below logic but didn't work bc for some cases @ordernumber or date filters might be null.

```sql
and sh.CustomerOrderNbr  = (@OrderNumber)
and (Convert(date, cr.CreateDt) between @StartDate and @EndDate)
```

Expecting to add a logic that can return date range and ordernumber filters
Or
either @ordernumber or @StartDate&EndDate

Comment: What is your question here exactly? You don't ask anything.

Comment: Checking everything twice probably doesn't help. You don't mention how you want to handle `null` values. Providing the data types would be helpful. You might find [`is null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-null-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [`coalesce`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) useful.

Comment: i need help with where clause that can return either all there filters result or just @ordernumber paramter or date range parameter

Comment: Could you be a little more vague, e.g. if `@StartDate` is tomorrow, `@EndDate` is `null` and `CreateDt` is `null` then you want to ... .

Comment: Sounds like you want a "[catch-all](https://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/)" or "[kitchen sink](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example)" query, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
and Convert(date, cr.CreateDt) between ISNULL(@StartDate,'2001-01-01') and isnull(@EndDate,'2099-01-01')
and ( 
        (ISNULL(@OrderNumber,'') <> '' and sh.CustomerOrderNbr  = @OrderNumber)
        OR
        (ISNULL(@ordernumber,'') = '' And sh.CustomerOrderNbr <>'')
    )
```

Came up with the solution.

Comment: you could simplify that a bit, especially the order number part with `and ( sh.CustomerOrderNbr = @OrderNumber OR  @OrderNumber IS NULL) `

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).